# Remove Datepicker Function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to remove datepicker function depending on the dropdownlist selected value.  I try the following codes, but it still shows the calendar when I put the cursor in the text box.  Please give me a suggestion.

```
$("#ddlSearchType").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Required Date" || $(this).val() == "Submitted Date") {
        $("#txtSearch").datepicker();
    } else {
        $("#txtSearch").datepicker("option", "disabled", true);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: "Required Date" and "Submitted Date" are not values of the dropdown, they are labels. Look for <option value="">Required Date</option> and the value you need will be in the `value` attribute of the dropdown.

Comment: why not load it at the document ready(date picker), than toggle hide/show depending on your select options?

Comment: I used "Required Date" and "Submitted Date" as values.  Yes, I could change them to 0,1,2,3 values later.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @c0mrade Yes, it is the last way I could think of.  But I am wondering that is there anyway to dynamically bind and revoke the jquery feature?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can try the enable/disable methods instead of using the option method:

```
$("#txtSearch").datepicker("enable");
$("#txtSearch").datepicker("disable");
```

This disables the entire textbox. So may be you can use [`datepicker.destroy()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-destroy) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddlSearchType").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "Required Date" || $(this).val() == "Submitted Date") {
            $("#txtSearch").datepicker();
        }
        else {
            $("#txtSearch").datepicker("destroy");
        }
    }).change();
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/faZ9u/).

Answer (score 24):

Destroy the datepicker's instance when you don't want it and create new instance whenever necessary.

I know this is ugly but only this seems to be working...

[**Check this out**](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/Vc4av/2/)

```
 $("#ddlSearchType").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Required Date" || $(this).val() == "Submitted Date") {
                $("#txtSearch").datepicker();

         }
          else {
                $("#txtSearch").datepicker("destroy");                    
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

Just bind the datepicker to a class rather than binding it to the id . Remove the class when you want to revoke the datepicker...

```
$("#ddlSearchType").change(function () { 
  if ($(this).val() == "Required Date" || $(this).val() == "Submitted Date")                   { 
    $("#txtSearch").addClass("mydate");
    $(".mydate").datepicker()
  } else { 
    $("#txtSearch").removeClass("mydate");
  } 
});
```

Comment: If this worked before, it currently isn't working now

Answer (score 3):

Well I had the same issue and tried "destroy" but that not worked for me. Then I found following work around
My HTML was:

```
<input placeholder="Select Date" id="MyControlId" class="form-control datepicker" type="text" />
```

Jquery That work for me:

```
$('#MyControlId').data('datepicker').remove();
```

Comment: Instead of other answeres, this worked for me, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

what about using the official [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy)?

According to the API doc:

> DESTROY: Removes the datepicker functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

Use:

`$("#txtSearch").datepicker("destroy");`

to restore the input to its normal behaviour and

`$("#txtSearch").datepicker(/*options*/);`

again to show the datapicker again.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I use. It has more lines but it will only create the datepicker once.

```
$('#txtSearch').datepicker({
    constrainInput:false,
    beforeShow: function(){
        var t = $('#ddlSearchType').val();
        if( ['Required Date', 'Submitted Date'].indexOf(t) ) {
            $('#txtSearch').prop('readonly', false);
            return false;
        }
        else $('#txtSearch').prop('readonly', true);
    }
});
```

The datepicker will not show unless the value of ddlSearchType is either "Required Date" or "Submitted Date"