# Disable datepicker without disabling input field

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Datepicker Function dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107465/remove-datepicker-function-dynamically)

In my web application i am using the datepicker. I am using the same page for create and edit the details. While editing the page the date should not be editable. I am disabling the datepicker by using the following code.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("disable");
```

But the above code also disables the input field also.(If the input field is disabled in edit mode the data is not posted to the PHP). I want to disable the datepicker without disabling the input field and i want to show the "ui-datepicker-trigger" icon. Can anyone help me out.
Following is the link to JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/Xppj6/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
```

In response to your comment:
if you want to preserve icon just do it manually, i.e. copy icon from DOM tree, destroy datepicker (this will remove icon from DOM) then reinsert it into DOM. May be not best performant but no human should notice unless you execute this thousands of times per second :)

basically my idea is to do something like that:

```
   $img = $('#datepicker').parent().find('img'); //fetch datepicker icon from DOM
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("destroy"); //destroy datepicker
   $('#datepicker').parent().append($img); //reappend icon into its original place
```

in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xppj6/7/
and a fiddle with both "disable" and "enable" button: http://jsfiddle.net/Xppj6/14/

**Note:** You will have to recreate datepicker completely if you need to undo this operation. You will also have to destroy manually appended icon before creating new datepicker (as new datepicker will createn ew icon)

**Refrence:**
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy

Comment: Using the destroy it removes the "ui-datepicker-trigger" icon, but i want to show the "ui-datepicker-trigger" icon

Comment: Edited my answer with simple solution to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to disable the datepicker without disabling the input field, but one thing you can do is create a hidden variable in which you can copy the value of the input field before psoting the data and then retrieve it on server.