# How to remove bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

In jQuery UI DatePicker, we are able to dynamically remove the datepicker from the textbox input. ([Remove Datepicker Function Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107465/remove-datepicker-function-dynamically))

Is it possible to do so in Bootstrap datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can do the trick:

showOnFocus

```
Boolean. Default: true
```

If false, the datepicker will be prevented from showing when the input field associated with it receives focus.