# datepicker : disable date selection before a date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to disable selection of date before (actualDate + 1 month).
I tried to use minDate property of datePicker but it doesn't work.
Could you help me ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group col-md-8 input-medium date date-picker desiredDeliveryDateDiv" id="deliveryDateInputGroup" data-date-format="M dd, yyyy">
    <input type="text" class="form-control desiredDeliveryDateInput" readonly="">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn default" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var deliveryDatePlusOneMonth = new Date();
deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.setMonth(deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.getMonth()+1);
deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.setDate(deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.getDate()+1);

// Initialize delivery date picker
$("#deliveryDateInputGroup").datepicker({
    minDate: deliveryDatePlusOneMonth
});

// By default, set the delivery date to actual date + 1 month
$("#deliveryDateInputGroup").datepicker('setDate', deliveryDatePlusOneMonth);

// Declare on change on delivery date to close the date picker once the user has selected a date
$('#deliveryDateInputGroup').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtdate").datepicker({
                minDate: 0
            });
        });
```

[Example](http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/98/JQuery-Date-Picker-example-to-disable-previous-dates.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try This it should work
// Declare on change on delivery date to close the date picker once the user      has selected a date
 $('#deliveryDateInputGroup').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
 });
```

You can find more Info on the below link
[Remove Datepicker Function dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107465/remove-datepicker-function-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  var deliveryDatePlusOneMonth = new Date();
deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.setMonth(deliveryDatePlusOneMonth.getMonth()+1);


// Initialize delivery date picker
$("#deliveryDateInputGroup").datepicker({
    minDate: deliveryDatePlusOneMonth
});

// By default, set the delivery date to actual date + 1 month
$("#deliveryDateInputGroup").datepicker('setDate', deliveryDatePlusOneMonth);

// Declare on change on delivery date to close the date picker once the user has selected a date
$('#deliveryDateInputGroup').on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZBEt/537/)