# Disable DatePicker icon trigger when date textbox is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented the date picker as below:

```js
$( ".apprvd_input_date" ).datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   showOn: "both",
   buttonImage: "../resources/images/date_picker.gif",
   buttonImageOnly: true                   
});
```

I have `<h:inputText disabled="#{bean.readOnly}" styleClass="apprvd_input_date" size="8"/>` I control the disabled property from bean variable and now the text box is disabled but still it allows me to pick the date using date picker. Can i hide the date picker icon on when it is disabled? I have around 10 textboxes using the date picker and wanna to do it for all.

Comment: Will you share the code on codepen

Comment: I tried the destroy method specified here, works perfect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107465/remove-datepicker-function-dynamically . Advantage of using this destroy method over $(".ui-datepicker-trigger") hide is, you can destroy only the elements you need to disable the date picker $(this).datePicker('destroy'), where as the former one will hide icon for every date picker in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will have to manually hide that date picker icon** as:

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rmdf32za/

```
function disableDate(){
  $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").addClass("hide");
  $(".apprvd_input_date").attr("disabled","disabled");
}

.hide{
  display:none;
}
```