# Difference between .Remove() and .Destroy() in Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107465/remove-datepicker-function-dynamically/6107981) here in stackoverflow. And I am wondering what is the difference between using `.remove()` and `.destroy` in the datepicker javascript cause when I tried to run it in an online compiler, it seem to perform the same way.

I was checking the jquery api documention and I can only see the destroy() method in it.

using .destroy()

```
 <button onclick="datepicker.destroy()">Destroy</button>
 <input id="datepicker" width="200" />
 <script>
     var datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker();
 </script>
```

using .remove()

```
 <button onclick="datepicker.remove()">Destroy</button>
 <input id="datepicker" width="200" />
 <script>
     var datepicker = $('#datepicker').datepicker();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

destroy() doesn't necessarily remove the element from the DOM.  Destroy will 'remove' saved states on the element and put it back to a pre-init state.  After destroying, you can re-initialize the same element.

In contrast, remove() will both destroy and remove the element.  Gone for good and good riddance to it!

Comment: Hi thank you for this. Is there an available documentation for the remove(), I cant seem to find it in the methods available in the jquery.ui datepicker widget here https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @Funky remember that `.remove()` is a JS/jQuery function: https://api.jquery.com/remove/ and `destroy` is a method of jQuery UI: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-destroy